# How to style nested divs

Tags: css

I want to change the colours of `div`s separately but don't want to use the following css.

The syntax I am using is as follows:

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper"><div><div><div><div><div><div><div>

</div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>
```

CSS:

```
div>div>div {background-color:yellow;}
div>div>div>div {background-color:green;}
div>div>div>div>div {background-color:indigo;}
div>div>div>div>div>div {background-color:violet;}
div>div>div>div>div>div>div {background-color:chocolate;}
div>div>div>div>div>div>div>div {background-color:brown;}
```

Comment: thats the best way or use classes.

Comment: You are showing some CSS code and saying you don’t want to use it. Is that a question? And the question in the title is far too broad.

Comment: I am not using it regularly and beginner for it would take little time to me get used to with it. I hope you will understand.

Answer (score 2):

Your best/only easy solution is using Classes or Id's and attaching them to your CSS sheet (as per Daniel's answer).

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper" class="ClassDiv1">
<div class="ClassDiv2">
<div class="ClassDiv3">
<div class="ClassDiv4">
<div class="ClassDiv5">
<div class="ClassDiv6">
<div class="ClassDiv7">
<div class="ClassDiv8">
```

CSS:

```
.ClassDiv1{background-color:yellow;}
.ClassDiv2{background-color:green;}
.ClassDiv3{background-color:indigo;}
```

etc.

If you want 1 color for 2 div tags you can just do this in your style:

```
.ClassDiv1 .ClassDiv2{background-color:brown;}
```

But seriously, rather go to W3Schools and learn a bit on CSS as it will help you a LOT!

Answer (score 2):

Use a naming convention.

```
.innerDiv1{
    background-color:yellow;
}

.innerDiv2{
    background-color:green;
}

.innerDiv3{
    background-color:indigo;
}

.innerDiv4{
    background-color:violet;
}

.innerDiv5{
    background-color:chocolate;
}

.innerDiv6{
    background-color:brown;
}
```

or you can use a pre-processor like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) and nested inside each other

```
.innerDiv{
    background-color:yellow;

    div{
        background-color:green;

        div{
            background-color:indigo;

            div{
                background-color:violet;

                div{
                    background-color:chocolate;

                    div{
                        background-color:brown;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go with classes:

```
.bg-yellow { background-color: yellow; }
...
.bg-brown { background-color: brown; }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="bg-yellow"><div><div><div><div><div><div class="bg-brown">
    </div></div></div></div></div></div></div>
</div>
```

Using this solution makes it easier to identify the color of the element when inspecting the HTML.

Comment: Actually, I was trying to reduce the length of the code but it seems there is no other way besides classes or ids. Thanks for alternative.